# It's possible to addOnPropertyChangedCallback on a @Bindable?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I would like to observe a `@Bindable` via Java, is it possible?

I read that I can observe a ObservableField on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885802/858257

But sometimes you need the primitive field and the best approach is using a `@Bindable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can. If you have a field marked with `@Bindable` and implement [`Observable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Observable.html), you can listen for changes to that field. Any bindable field must notify when changed. For example:

```
public class Item extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;
    private int stockCount;

    @Bindable
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getStockCount() { return stockCount; }
    public void setStockCount(int stockCount) {
        this.stockCount = stockCount;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.stockCount);
    }
}
```

You can then listen for changes on this object. I used `BaseObservable` as the base class for this data class because it implements the observability for me.

```
public void listenForStockChange(Item item) {
    item.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
            if (propertyId == BR.stockCount) {
                Item item = (Item) sender;
                // Do whatever you want when the stock changes
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much :)