# Android addOnPropertyChangedCallback can't update class old data with new value data

Tags: android, observable

in `watcher` of this class `observablePerson` method `name` property couldnt update with new value and that have old data always

`LoginViewModel` class:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    public final ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<String> family = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<String> profilePicUrl = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<Boolean> progress = new ObservableField<>();
    private final ObservableField<Person> observablePerson = new ObservableField<>();

    public LoginViewModel() {
        observablePerson.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender,
                                          int propertyId) {
                Person person = getObservablePerson();

                if (person != null) {
                    name.set(getName(person));
                    family.set(getFamily(person));
                    profilePicUrl.set(getProfilePicUrl(person));
                    progress.set(getProgress(person));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcherAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!Objects.equals(name.get(), s.toString())) {
                name.set(s.toString());
            }

            observablePerson.notifyChange();
        }
    };

    public String getFamily(Person person) {
        return person.getFamily();
    }

    public String getName(Person person) {
        return person.getName();
    }

    public String getProfilePicUrl(Person person) {
        return person.getProfilePicUrl();
    }

    public boolean getProgress(Person person) {
        return person.isProgress();
    }

    public Person getObservablePerson() {
        return observablePerson.get();
    }

    public void setObservablePerson(Person observablePerson) {
        this.observablePerson.set(observablePerson);
    }
}
```